# badly formatted heading line in debian package changelog

Tags: packaging, debian, debuild, changelog

By running `debuild`, I find the following warnings:

```
# debuild 
debuild: warning:     debian/changelog(l1): badly formatted heading line
LINE: my_package (0.3-1) unstable; urgency=low
```

Where is my mistake?

Here is my `debian/changelog`

```
my_package (0.3-1) trusty; urgency=low

    * First release:

-- My Name  <mymail@gmail.com> Tue Oct 11 21:22:15 CEST 2016
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is due to the underscore in the package name itself (my_package). Debian package names can consist of only lower case letters (a-z), digits (0-9), plus (+) and minus (-) signs, and periods (.)

There is a really detailed blog post on blog.packagecloud.io that talks about package names and versions.

http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/07/14/using-dh-make-to-prepare-debian-packages/#understanding-the-package-name-and-version

And another post on using debuild to build debian packages:

http://blog.packagecloud.io/debian/debuild/packaging/2015/06/08/buildling-deb-packages-with-debuild/

Comment: It's great to reference some random blog post, but going to [the official Debian source](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Source) is even better.